# Caesar Cipher: How to deal with character that deletes information

Tags: excel, python-3.x, vba

I have a question that is asking for encrypt a message, using a modified version of a Caesar Cipher. The catch being that I am expected to use all 256 characters of the extended ASCII library. This part is reasonably straightforward.

However, when I was running the encryption, the length of the message changed. After tracking down the issue, it seems that if a particular shift is used, some of the characters are converted to ASCII 127, which is the character for "delete". As such, it deletes the previous character, instead of appending a character to the message.

Any suggestions on how to get around this, while maintaining the integrity of the cipher?

If it helps, I can write the solution in either Python and VBA.

Note: I posted this on [Cryptography](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/77420/caesar-cipher-how-to-encrypt-a-character-that-deletes-information) as well, and they suggested hex notation, which I am examining as an alternative.

Edit:

Code in VBA:

```vb
bLength = 1
cText = vbNullString
fOffset = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(-255, 255)

While bLength <= aLength

    dCharacter = vbNullString
    eCharacter = vbNullString

    dCharacter = Mid(Cells(2, 1), bLength, 1)

    If 0 > (Asc(dCharacter) + fOffset) Then
        eCharacter = Chr(Asc(dCharacter) + fOffset + 255)

    ElseIf 255 < (Asc(dCharacter) + fOffset) Then
        eCharacter = Chr(Asc(dCharacter) + fOffset - 255)

    Else
        eCharacter = Chr(Asc(dCharacter) + fOffset)

    End If

    cText = cText + eCharacter

    bLength = bLength + 1

Wend
```

Comment: Where is your code? Can you show how you implemented it?

Comment: Don't use `+` as string concatenation in VBA, use `&`: `cText = cText & eCharacter`.

Comment: @FunThomas: fixed that. Seems to be working better now